# onServerClick doesn't work in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this code that when button trigger it will display a alert box and do something in the database but it doesn't work with onServerClick.

Here is the Code.

```
 <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" codeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" inherits="MainPage, App_Web_rlctbjj5" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
 <script runat="server">
  void ButtonLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  string script = "alert('" + TextBox2.Text + "');";

 System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Test", script, true);
 string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TDBSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

 string query = "SELECT UserID FROM [IBSI].[sec].[Users] WHERE UserName = @1";

 if (query != null)
 {
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
   {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
     {
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@1", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
         while (rdr.Read())
        {

         TextBox3.Text=rdr["UserID"].ToString() ;


        }
      }
    }
  }
}
else 
{
  Response.Write("<p>No customer selected</p>"); 
}

}
</script>
```

With this HTML

```
 <button jsid="ButtonLogin" id="ButtonLogin" onServerClick="ButtonLogin_OnClick" runat="server"  dojotype="dijit.form.Button" style="float: right;
                            padding: 5px 15px 0px 0px;">
                           Login</button>
```

This code is inside a FORM SERVER RUNAT

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can run only on client side but you have put an alert inside a script running on server side.
What you need to do is add an attribute to the button from server side to alert user and then post the request back to server with `return true` at the end. You can add following snippet inside `Page_Load` method.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
   ButtonLogin.Attributes.Add("onclick",
     "alert(
      document.getElementById('" + TextBox2.ClientID + "').value); return true;");
}
```

Comment: tried it but still the same, i think it because im using a dojotype that is calling a javascript also and it cant be use the same time with onserverclick.

Comment: Why dont you use `<asp:Button ...` or button type `<input ..` instead? Any reason?

Comment: using ASP:button will use the runat server itself this means i cant use dojotype. havent tried using input type but i think still same as i am using right now.